# I don't understand how the code works in vhdl?

Tags: vhdl

```
ARCHITECTURE behavior OF testbench IS 
   signal a,b : integer := 0;

BEGIN
 p1:process
    begin 
        a<= b +1  after 3 ns ;
        wait on a;
 end process;


 p2:process
    begin 
        b<= a+1 after 5 ns ;
        wait on a;
 end process;

  END;
```

Comment: You would be helped by formatting the code properly. Put the `process`, `begin` and everything ending with a `;` on a separate line.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Which bit don't you understand? Any of it? Did you simulate it?

Answer (score 1):

So what part do you not understand? The above code is a good example for a simulation only code which is not synthesizable, because of the `after` statements. You can´t implement this kind of statement which hardware.

Also your code doesn´t do very much. Start the simulation and watch the waveform diagram.

[image]

Then try to understand the function of your code line by line. The testbench execute the `a <= b + 1` instruction after 3 ns, so your `a` will increase by one. Same for your `b`. Now the `process` is waiting for `a`. A `process` is a sequential part in your design, so the change of `a` doesn´t affect the `wait for a`, because the part is executed before the `wait on a`. The same is for your second process. Both processes are parallel, but each process is sequential.

Maybe you get a better idea on what is going on when you change your code:

```
p2:process
    begin 
        b <= 1 after 5 ns ;
        wait on a;
        b <= 2 ;
end process;
```

[image]

Now you see that your `b` will be set to `2` after your `a` changed, because the `wait on a` has finished. After 5 ns `b` gets set to `1`, because your `after` has expired.

Additional you see that the processes are parallel, because the change of `a` affect `b` at the same time.

Comment: Delay clauses are ignored in synthesis, wherein the behavior won't match simulation.